# Can Razor engine parse Html.Encode(ViewData["varname"])?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Passing data (simple string) from Controller to View I have in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["user"] = System.Environment.UserName.ToUpper();
            return View();
        }
```

and in my cshtml

```
<h2>Welcome <%=Html.Encode(ViewData["user"]) %></h2>
```

I checked and verifieid that the username does get populated, however, it does not get displayed on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Using asp.net mvc 3 with Razor

Comment: As a side note, razor automatically encodes HTML so you don't need the `Html.Encode()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those alligator tags (`<%= %>`) are from the old ASP.NET view engine.

You need to use Razor syntax:

```
<h2>Welcome @Html.Encode(ViewData["user"])</h2>
```

But as other posters pointed out, the Razor engine prefers to encode HTML by default, so all you need is:

```
<h2>Welcome @ViewData["user"]</h2>
```

If you ever want to *not* encode something, use the `Html.Raw()` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
<h2>Welcome @ViewData["user"]</h2>
```